# Why hibernate returns same column with different alias name?

Tags: hibernate

```
@Entity
public class Vehicle {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int number;
    private String name;
    
    @ManyToOne()
    private UserDetails user;
    
    public UserDetails getUserDetails() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUserDetails(UserDetails user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Vehicle [number=" + number + ", name=" + name+"]";
    }
    
    

}
@Entity
public class UserDetails {

    @Id
    private int userId;

    private String userName;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Vehicle> vehicle=new ArrayList<Vehicle>();

    public List<Vehicle> getVehicle() {
        return vehicle;
    }

    public void setVehicle(List<Vehicle> vehicle) {
        this.vehicle = vehicle;
    }

    @Lob
    private String Description;

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return Description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        Description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserDetails [userId=" + userId + ", userName=" + userName + ", vehicle=" + vehicle + ", Description="
                + Description + "]";
    }
```

}

I am getting the below result. But in this result the highlighted lines have same column name but with different aliases. Why hibernate is picking up same cloumn?

Hibernate: drop table if exists hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: drop table if exists UserDetails
Hibernate: drop table if exists Vehicle
Hibernate: create table hibernate_sequence (next_val bigint) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )
Hibernate: create table UserDetails (userId integer not null, Description longtext, userName varchar(255), primary key (userId)) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: create table Vehicle (number integer not null, name varchar(255), user_userId integer, primary key (number)) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: alter table Vehicle add constraint FKj7mb7jwf8fhf3b6naff1uy9b4 foreign key (user_userId) references UserDetails (userId)
Jun 11, 2021 9:15:22 AM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Hibernate: insert into UserDetails (Description, userName, userId) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Vehicle (name, user_userId, number) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select userdetail0_.userId as userid1_0_0_, userdetail0_.Description as descript2_0_0_, userdetail0_.userName as username3_0_0_ from UserDetails userdetail0_ where userdetail0_.userId=?
Hibernate: select vehicle0_.number as number1_1_0_, vehicle0_.name as name2_1_0_, vehicle0_.user_userId as user_use3_1_0_, userdetail1_.userId as userid1_0_1_, userdetail1_.Description as descript2_0_1_, userdetail1_.userName as username3_0_1_ from Vehicle vehicle0_ left outer join UserDetails userdetail1_ on vehicle0_.user_userId=userdetail1_.userId where vehicle0_.number=?
Hibernate: **select vehicle0_.user_userId as user_use3_1_0_, vehicle0_.number as number1_1_0_, vehicle0_.number as number1_1_1_, vehicle0_.name as name2_1_1_, vehicle0_.user_userId as user_use3_1_1_ from Vehicle vehicle0_ where vehicle0_.user_userId=?**
user name ==> UserDetails [userId=0, userName=Vickram, vehicle=[Vehicle [number=1, name=Car]], Description=Tall white]
vehicle ===>UserDetails [userId=0, userName=Vickram, vehicle=[Vehicle [number=1, name=Car]], Description=Tall white]

Comment: Could you please show the hql queries that you execute.

Comment: I didn't write hql queries. Hibernate generated queries for me. Please refer below the code. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That's because Hibernate before version 6.0 had no dedicated SQL AST model to deduplicate this. Every column mapping for an attribute was just "passed-through" to the SQL i.e. it selects the respective mapped columns for every attribute that needs to be initialized.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you explain in this in a layman terms since it is difficult to understand. Thank you. Please explain in it more elaborately

Comment: In layman terms, that's just how it is before Hibernate 6.0. Don't worry about it right now, it will get better in the future when you update Hibernate.